# I don't know why I am having an error message like this CLASS Is Not Abstract And Does Not Override Abstract Method Error

Tags: java

I don't know why I am having an error message like this CLASS Is Not Abstract And Does Not Override Abstract Method Error

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

class Editor extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

        JTextArea t;
        JFrame f;
        Editor()
```

Comment: There must be more in this error message. Which method does your class not override?

Comment: When you create a class that implements some interface (`ActionListener` in this case), you **must** implement interface's methods unless your class is an abstract one (apparently it's not). So you need to add a method `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { /* some actions go here */ }` to your class

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), `ActionListener` is an `interface` that contains the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`. If you want to `implement` it, you must either declare your class `abstract` (can not be instantiated, can have `abstract` methods without body), or override its method. That is because that's what interfaces do, force the classes implementing them to override their methods.

```
class Editor extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```